Woman trying to find her child or husband begins to fade away or turn invisible
It has been some years since I saw this movie, and I don't remember much of it, but what I do remember is about this woman, I think she is trying to find her child or husband, if I remember right she is or has lost her memories, and she begins to fade away or turn invisible and is trying to get back to normal, if I remember right she is also seeing some people in suits that's suspicious and tries to maybe kill her or erase her from the memories of everyone she knows.
I hope it's all pretty accurate, would be a big help if people could find it, it has at least been 5 - 7 years since I saw it.

It's not eternal sunshine of the spotless mind right? If you don't know that movie I'll post an answer. It's the only movie I can think of with amnesia, loss of a significant other, fading away, and people trying to keep her from he SO. Starring Jim Carey and Kate winslet.

Sounds like The Adjustment Bureau from 2011 with Matt Damon and Emily Blunt, loosely based on a short story by Phillip K. Dick. Men in suits from "The Adjustment Bureau" can stop time, change timelines, and manipulate memories to make sure that history unfolds according to "The Plan." In it, though, it's mostly Damon who is the main character, not a woman as in the film you remember.



